# How to create Particles Webpage Background without animation (pure css)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have some particles like what it looks like in particles.js, but without any animations and with pure CSS code. I know this can be done, but I can not find any example or tutorial online how to achieve it. The animation part is annoyed for both css-solution and js-solution because of high CPU usage. So I am trying to find a way to remove animation and use pure css for better performance.

- Particles Background References:

  - https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/
  - https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/2-ways-to-create-an-animated-particle-background--cms-30224

Thanks a lot.

Edited: maybe a lightweight javascript version is fine too as long as it's lightweight.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the particles animated or do you want them to be in fixed positions? The second reference linked already shows a CSS only based solution for animated particles.

Comment: @David Sorry that I thought I expressed clearly, but I didn't. The title of this issue shows that I don't want the animation at all. I just want to create fixed position particles. The second reference actually shows scss version instead of css version. I am wondering if it's can be done with a few lines in css. If I compile that scss from the second reference to css, it will be a huge file with about 400 lines. All I want is a lightweight few lines css or js solution for fixed position particles. As light as possible, I want to minimize both download size and browser loading time. Thanks!

Comment: Most parts of the compiled CSS in your second example are related to the animations of the particles. Since you don't want the animation, you can get rid of roughly around 60% of the CSS.

Comment: @David thanks a lot for the reply. I never use scss before. I will try to remove the compiled css to see what I can achieve. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the compiled CSS from your second example and remove everything in it which is there for animation purposes.

In case you don't mind a (small) JavaScript based solution, see below. It uses the `<canvas>` element to draw particles:

```js
(function (runModule) {
  // init. renders 200 particles into the element with ID "bg".
  // particles have a radius between 3 and 9px (6 +- 3) and
  // can either be red, blue or green
  runModule(document.querySelector('#bg'), 200, 6, [
    '#c00',
    '#0c0',
    '#00c'
  ]);
})(function (canvas, particleCount, particleRadius, particleColors) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var particles = [];
  var particle;
  
  create();
  render();
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  
  function makeParticle (radius, colors) {
    return {
      x: between(radius, canvas.width - radius),
      y: between(radius, canvas.height - radius),
      r: between(radius * 0.5, radius * 1.5),
      c: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    };
  }

  function create () {
    particles = [];
    while (particles.length < particleCount) {
      particle = makeParticle(particleRadius, particleColors);
      particles.push(particle);
    }
  }
  
  function render () {
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
   particles.forEach(function (particle) {
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(particle.x, particle.y, particle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
     ctx.closePath();
     ctx.fillStyle = particle.c;
     ctx.fill();
    })
  }
    
  function resize () {
    var rect = canvas.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvas.width = rect.width;
    canvas.height = rect.height;
    create();
    render();
  }
  
  function between (a, b) {
    return Math.round(Math.max(a, Math.random() * b));
  }
});
```

```css
#bg {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bg" width="320" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the complete code. I have upvoted and marked this as the answer. It works very well. ^_^